# Why doesn't my neural network learn a rule, even when trained on a large dataset?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I can't get my neural network to perform well at all. It is supposed to classify a 21-bit encoded input into binary yes or no outputs. The division of yes:no targets is roughly 20:80. At first I had a small data set, so I acquiesced to it outputting close to 100% 'no'. But now I have ~20,000 records, and it still outputs 'no' ~100% of the time. Why is it incapable of learning the rule for classifying an input as 'yes', does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

My input vector is 21x18942. My target vector is 2x18942. I don't do anything fancy with the neural network, the code is simply

`net=patternnet(20)`

`a = sim(net,targets);`

`[net,tr] = train(net,inputs,targets);`

`outputs = net(inputs);`

`plotconfusion(targets, outputs)`

and I have tried other standard neural networks available within matlab, e.g. `net = feedforwardnet(10, 'traingd');` with the same result.

Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong, or if there is some sort of limitation to these matlab neural network toolboxes that is causing a problem?

Any thoughts here would be very much appreciated

Comment: perhaps the data is not separable, leading to this result.  Not every data set can be classified in this manner.

Comment: @DmitryGalchinsky I doubt having a held-out set would help here because even the training accuracy is not good now.

Comment: @DaKuang, I made a mistake, I thought small data set is a training and big was just checked. I'll remove this

Comment: @Photon Hi, sorry for not getting back to you sooner. I think this is a really good point and I've been thinking about it and I'm about to try an implementation with my data re-organised hopefully to be separable. thanks very much